# Why email can't be read from Maildir?

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot

I have Postfix configured to deliver to Maildir-format mailboxes:

```
$ cat /etc/postfix/main.cf
home_mailbox=Maildir/
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
```

I have Dovecot configured the same:

```
$ cat /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
```

But the `mail` command seems unable to read my Maildir mailboxes, and seems to be telling me that mail is not being delivered how I think.

Every time that mail is sent to `user@xx.yy`, it can be read by the command:

```
mail -f  /var/mail/user
```

indicating that it is being delivered there instead of into `~user/Maildir`.  Moreover, `mail` fails to read that mail directory when invoked as:

```
mail -f /home/user/Maildir/new
```

Why is this?  How do I configure Postfix et al. to deliver to mail directories?  And how do I get the `mail` command to show the mail that is in them?

Comment: Because `mail` expects messages to start with `From_`, and Maildir down't allow `From_` lines.

Comment: There are two questions here. Could you please clarify whether this is a question about Postfix or `mail`?  Are mail being delivered (are there files in the Maildir folder)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mail` utility usually can't handle Maildir mailboxes.

Use another mail client, such as `mutt` for example, that can.

```
mutt -f /home/user/Maildir
```